# Determine locationKey from path with react-router

Tags: react-router

Say I have this route configuration:

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
      <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

And say the current url is: /inbox/messages/6

Lets say that the locationKeys for pased into each component are as follows:

```
/ = "loc1" (as accessed in App component as this.props.location.key)
/inbox = "loc2"
/messages/:id = "loc3"
```

Is there anyway I can ask react-router to give me the location key for a given route path?  For example I want to pass in "messages/:id" and get back "loc3"

Alternatively, is there anyway I can get a reference to the react component currently rendered at that path? I.e. if I pass in "messages/:id" I get back the instance of Message that is currently showing message id 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you go to `/messages/123` and then to `/inbox` and then to `/messages/123`, the key is different for the second visit to the message, so, no.

The key is usually not the relevant thing, you want `location.state`.

To get the components, well, you are the component, so `this` and `this.props.children`.

Comment: But I only care about the current locationKey

Comment: And say I'm not the component, rather a deeply nested child component.  And say I want to determine the current locationKey for /inbox ...

Comment: I'm using the locationKey to persist UI state in my redux store...  Should I be using location.state instead?